# How to write Kotlin class in one project and call this class in other Kotlin project (All in Kotlin)?

Tags: function, class, kotlin, call

I am new to Kotlin and I am struggle with the designing of one Kotlin project that its classes and functions can be called from other Kotlin project. The language I use is pure Kotlin.
What is the procedure to build such Kotlin project? (that its classes and functions call be called by other Kotlin project) And what procedure for project B to call classes and functions from project A?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Just the same as Java (where there will be a lot more online documentation).  In short the brief process is

1. You need to use a build system such as Maven or Gradle to compile and create the artefacts for project A.  These are commonly distributed as a "jar" file which is really just a zip file with a special file extension and organisation of the classes within.  You have to name to this artefact via the build system `groupName` `artefactName` `version`
2. Then in the project B, using the build system again your reference that artefact  `groupName` `artefactName` `version`.  Secondly, inside the Project B code you `import` the package where the entry point is for your code

If you use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ it will guide you through a lot of it. There are many tutorials... but I suggest you go looking first for java because of the very large number of tutorials/videos to choose from and then when you get that working start afresh with Kotlin

Comment: The magic word for how you add the artefact is ‘_dependency_’. If your build system knows that project knows that project B has a dependency on project A, and knows where to get it from, then it should take care of the rest.